# Database level encryption in AWS 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.3 engine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We are trying to implement database level encryption in Mysql Aurora instance. Engine is - 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.3

We tried to install keyring plugin like we do on prem, but it gives error.

install plugin keyring_file soname "keyring_file.so"

Error Code: 1126. Can't open shared library '/rdsdbbin/oscar-8.0.mysql_aurora.3.03.1.0.29187.0/lib/plugin/keyring_file.so' (errno: 2 /rdsdbbin/oscar-8.0.mysql_aurora.3.03.1.0.29187.0/lib/plugin/keyring_file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or di)

Is there anyway to perform database level encryption in aurora mysql. AWS team confirmed that RDS does not support anything similar to keyring. What other options we have?

We have already encrypted at AWS level using KMS keys

Comment: You got your answer from the AWS team. The alternative is to run your own MySQL Server on EC2, then you can add plugins for whatever you want. You can't add plugins to RDS or Aurora, besides those already enabled by AWS.

Comment: Alternative is not suitable. Aurora was chosen as it provides much better performance and HA along with it being a managed service. With own ec2 we need to manage everthing from updates, security, etc.